# tm_map has parallel::mclapply error in R 3.0.1 on Linux

Tags: r, tm, mclapply

I am using R 3.0.1 on Platform: i486-pc-linux-gnu (32-bit).I am trying to use tm_map from the tm library.I have 4080 words in my  SmartStopWord list. But when I execute the this code :

```
library(tm)
Get_Corpus <- system.file("texts","MyFile", package = "tm")
(corpus <- Corpus(DirSource(Get_Corpus, encoding = "UTF-8"),readerControl
 = list(language = "lat")))
show(corpus)
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeWords, stopwords("SmartStopWord"))
```

I get this error:

```
Message d'avis :
In parallel::mclapply(x, FUN, ...) :
all scheduled cores encountered errors in user code
```

Does anyone know a solution for this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [tm\_map has parallel::mclapply error in R 3.0.1 on Mac](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18287981/tm-map-has-parallelmclapply-error-in-r-3-0-1-on-mac)

Comment: Despite the title, it very likely applies to Linux as well.

Comment: Exactly i saw that but the solution it could not help me

Comment: What happens when you run: `stemDocument(corpus[[1]])`?

Comment: Erreur dans SnowballC::wordStem(x, language) : 
  language `lat' is not available for stemming

Comment: I divise my SmartStopword list in 2 List,and i don't have any error now.I transfer data to ldaformat but in my Vocabulary i found the words which are in StopWord list .I thinks my SmartStopWord could not filter all of words.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say, what happens when you run `removeWords(corpus[[1]], stopwords("SmartStopWord"))`?.

Comment: I get this Error : Erreur dans UseMethod("tm_map", x) : 
  pas de méthode pour 'tm_map' applicable pour un objet de classe "c('PlainTextDocument', 'TextDocument', 'character')"