# R tm In mclapply(content(x), FUN, ...) : all scheduled cores encountered errors in user code

Tags: r, twitter, rstudio, tm, mclapply

When I run the following codes to the penultimate line, I got Warning message:

> In mclapply(content(x), FUN, ...) :   all scheduled cores encountered
>   errors in user code

When I run the final line, I got

> "Error in UseMethod(\"words\") : \n  no applicable method for
>   'words' applied to an object of class \"character\"\n" attr(,"class")
>   "try-error" attr(,"condition")

The following link is a reproducible example which we can copy/paste into R and run.

https://github.com/weijia2013/mclapply-issue/blob/master/codes

I just start learn R and I'll be appreciate your help.

```
library(devtools)
install_github("twitteR", username="geoffjentry")
library(twitteR)
setup_twitter_oauth("API Key", "API Secret")

rdmTweets <- userTimeline('rdatamining', n=200)
(nDocs <- length(rdmTweets))
rdmTweets[11:15]
for (i in 11:15) {cat(paste("[[", i, "]] ", sep="")) + writeLines(strwrap(rdmTweets[[i]]$getText(), width=73))}

df <- do.call("rbind", lapply(rdmTweets, as.data.frame))
dim(df)
library(tm)
library(SnowballC)
library(RWeka)
library(rJava)
library(RWekajars)

myCorpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(df$text))
myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, tolower)
myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, removePunctuation)
myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, removeNumbers)
removeURL <- function(x) gsub("http[[:alnum:]]*", "", x)
myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, removeURL)
myStopwords <- c(stopwords("english"), "available", "via")
myStopwords <- setdiff(myStopwords, c("r", "big"))
myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, removeWords, myStopwords)



myCorpusCopy <- myCorpus
myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, stemDocument)
for (i in 11:15) {cat(paste("[[", i, "]] ", sep="")) + writeLines(strwrap(myCorpus[[i]], width=73))}

myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, stemCompletion, dictionary=myCorpusCopy)

inspect(myCorpus[11:15])

sessionInfo()

R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/C/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[7] base     

other attached packages:
[1] RWekajars_3.7.11-1 rJava_0.9-6        RWeka_0.4-23      
[4] SnowballC_0.5      tm_0.6             NLP_0.1-3         
[7] twitteR_1.1.8      devtools_1.5      

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] bit_1.1-12     bit64_0.9-4    digest_0.6.4   evaluate_0.5.5
[5] grid_3.1.1     httr_0.4       memoise_0.2.1  parallel_3.1.1
[9] RCurl_1.95-4.1 rjson_0.2.14   slam_0.1-32    stringr_0.6.2 
[13] tools_3.1.1    whisker_0.3-2
```

Answer (score 38):

Try using the code as follows:

```
myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, stemDocument,lazy=TRUE).
myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, tolower,lazy=TRUE) etc.
```

I think the new *tm* package requires this explicitly.

Comment: This fixed OP's exact problem for me.

Comment: This fixed the same problem for me! Thanks @Charles Copley. :)

Comment: Why is the following NOT the correct syntax?  myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, content_transformer(stemDocument), lazy=TRUE)

Answer (score 2):

I tried the solution provided by @Charles Copley but did not work in my code.
For later google searchers, another alternative solution is to set the number of cores to 1.

```
corpus = tm_map(corpus, tolower, mc.cores = 1)
```

This post [tm_map has parallel::mclapply error in R 3.0.1 on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18287981/tm-map-has-parallelmclapply-error-in-r-3-0-1-on-mac?noredirect=1&lq=1) provided a useful explanation.