# Why is DocumentTermMatrix running out of memory when plenty left?

Tags: r, tm

I'm getting the following memory allocation error when trying to run `DocumentTermMatrix` from the `tm` package. Not sure why this is happening as my machine has 128 gigs of memory and the corpus is just 3 gigs.

```
Error in mcfork() :
  unable to fork, possible reason: Cannot allocate memory
Calls: DocumentTermMatrix ... content.VCorpus -> materialize -> mclapply -> lapply -> FUN -> mcfork
```

This is all that is being called:

```
library(tm)
text <- read.csv('/path/to/text.csv', ...)

vct <- VCorpus(VectorSournce(text[,2]))
vct <- tm_map(vct, removeWords, stopwords("english"), mc.cores=1)
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(vct)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20556300/2985049) post, I figured out how to fix this by limiting the number of cores used. Since there is no explicit option via `DocumentTermMatrix`, I had to do it via `options`:

```
num.cores <- getOption("mc.cores")
options(mc.cores=1)
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(vct)
options(mc.cores=num.cores)
```